# Keycloak API :- Identify Users Realm for login

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

I am creating a microservice that will proxy keycloak for user creation, reset password, login etc. I don't want to expose any keycloak page like re-set password or login page so I am using the keycloak API and everything is fine so far.

The only issue is for login, where I need to know the realm to get the token as the API to get the token is realm specific.

```
realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

So is there a way to get a list of all the users from all the realms by admin user?
or any other way to find it?

Comment: I am confused your question. you want to get all of users by each realm? or logged-in user list by each realm?

Comment: So, when user submits userId and password on my webform (not keycloack form) I have to send an API request to Keycloak on realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/token. 
and for that, I need to know which REALM_NAME the user belongs to.

Comment: Thanks, it makes me clear. I answer for your question. hope to help it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the realm information by decode user's access token.

The "iss" (issuer) claim identifies the principal that issued the JWT.

This is decode example by JWT.io
[image]

I demo make two realms (realm1 and realm2)
each realm add single user (both user same username: user and password: 1234)
[image]

[image]
And call get access token and decode it by Python

```
import requests
import ast
import jwt

def get_issuer(realm, user_name, password):
    url = 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/'+realm+'/protocol/openid-connect/token'
    body = {
        'client_id': 'admin-cli',
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username' : user_name,
        'password': password
    }
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers).content.decode('utf-8')
    token = ast.literal_eval(response)['access_token']
    # print(token)
    decoded = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
    # print(decoded)
    return decoded['iss']

print('realm1 with user -->', get_issuer('realm1','user','1234'))
print('realm2 with user -->', get_issuer('realm2','user','1234'))
```

get this output

```
$python get_realm.py
realm1 with user --> http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm1
realm2 with user --> http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm2
```

If you want to get all users of realm,
you can get this API with master realm's admin token

**GET /{realm}/users**

Comment: thanks for taking the effort, appreciate it.
I think I failed to explain my question correctly,
in your code, when you invoke get_issuer('realm1','user','1234')) you have hardcoded realm1 and reaml2, I can't do that, because I will have 1000s of realms and the user can belong to any one of them so based on user I want to find out the realm it belongs to even before the token is available.
But I gathered that its not possible  so I am taking an approach to determine the realm based on other parameters and then use the code just like you have mentioned.
thanks again for your help.

Comment: So you want to get realm from access token(don't know which realm)?

Comment: Or from user (don't know belong which realm) to get realm?

Comment: the 2nd one, from user ID not knowing which realm the user belongs to.

Comment: OK, 2nd one, still two scenarios #1 by username or  #2 by user's access token to know which realm.  next my question #1 or #2 scenario?

Comment: username because to get the token, I need to know the realm. If I have the token, then there is no issue.

Comment: OK, I will demo it by Add another answer in here.

Comment: I added demo for finding a username belong to which realm.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with No_One, I realize he want to get a relam name by username.

I made 600 realms and 3 users for each realm. So total user 1.8K and each user unique username. (If may same username, we can extend username and e-mail). I made python program to create relams and users.

So I demo search realm by username with for loop.
Check username exist for every realm

***For loop all of relams***

**{keycloak_URL}/auth/admin/realms/{realm_name}/users/?username={user_name}**

if you want to get list of realms,

**{keycloak-url}/auth/admin/realms**

The realm name format is **realm_0xxx**

example) realm_0001, realm_0002, ..., realm_0600

each ream has three users

example) In realm_0001,

**user01_in_realm0001,
user02_in_realm0001,
user03_in_realm0001**

In realm_0002,

user01_in_realm0002,
user02_in_realm0002,
user03_in_realm0002
...
In realm_0600,

user01_in_realm0600,
user02_in_realm0600,
user03_in_realm0600

This Python code search user by for loop

```
import admin
import random

admin = admin.Admin()

token = admin.get_master_token()

random_realm_num = random.randint(1, 600)
random_user_num = random.randint(1, 3)

realm_name = "realm_{:04d}".format(random_realm_num)
user_name = "user{:02d}_in_realm{:04d}".format(random_user_num, random_realm_num)
print('random realm_name:', realm_name)
print('random user_name:', user_name)

found = False
for realm_index in range(1,600,1):
    realm_name = "realm_{:04d}".format(realm_index)
    if(admin.is_user_exist(token, realm_name, user_name)):
        print('user_name:', user_name,' belong to',realm_name)
        found = True
        break

if (not found):
    print('user_name:', user_name,'is not belong to any realms')
```

This admin class

```
from urllib import response
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import requests
import ast
import json

class Admin:
    # Keycloak master realm URL
    url = 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token'

    # Keycloak master credential
    params = {
        'client_id': 'admin-cli',
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username' : 'admin',
        'password': 'admin'
    }

    def get_master_token(self):
        try:
            response = requests.post(self.url, self.params, verify=False).content.decode('utf-8')
        except HTTPError as http_err:
            print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
            print('Keycloak container is not running, Please check your docker container!')
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            return ast.literal_eval(response)['access_token']

    def is_user_exist(self, token, realm_name, user_name):
        url ='http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/'+realm_name+'/users/?username='+user_name.replace(" ", "%20")

        headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ str(token)
        }
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            # print (response)
            # print (response.content)
            # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
            response.raise_for_status()
        except HTTPError as http_err:
            print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
        else:
            # print('Success!')
            # print(response.text)
            if len(response.content) == 2: # []
                return False
            if (json.loads(response.text)[0]['username'] == user_name.lower()):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Result

```
random realm_name: realm_0430
random user_name: user03_in_realm0430
user_name: user03_in_realm0430  belong to realm_0430

[Done] exited with code=0 in 21.248 seconds
```

Comment: @No_One, No problem, I realized too many realms is not good an idea. It makes a huge resource and slow speed. Any reason to use over 1000 realms?

Comment: yeah, we decided to identify the user's realm with some other means. either by adding it to the login form, via URL or storing the mapping so we don't have to iterate over all realms.

Comment: In a single realm, set of users and multiple clients  is common design pattern. user name or e-mail also can identify. User specific information can store/retrieve to/from user's attribute. It also leverage quick search user and authorization benefit by scope or resource based access control.

Answer (score 0):

We also encountered such problem but we finally implemented by this way:

1. create a new SPI and provide a new rest endpoint like '/realm-list'
2. it will return a list of realms that doesn't require admin privilege to access
3. provide a page to list and choose your realm and than click a button
4. forward current page to login page(the realm will reprenset in url path)

one thing needs to note, the backend of keycloak needs to check if user is logged in, we add a new cookie value to mark whether the user is logged in.