# Access to self hosted gitlab instance (normal/not API!) with users SAML kerberos token?

Tags: python, python-requests, gitlab, keycloak, saml

Given there is a selfhosted Gitlab instance in which a SAML login to keycloak is activated.
The SAML login in Keycloak works with Kerberos.

I want to create an app that accesses the Gitlab instance in the name of the user to access functions **not provided by the API**.

Is there a way to access the Gitlab Page, using Python and the users Kerberos Token?

I am already able to retrieve the Kerberos Token from Keycloak, i.e. to get an OAuth 2.0 access token.
Also when I copy the Cookie information from the Browser into the `request.session` I am able to access the Gitlab page from my Python app as wanted.

But looking on the requests done within the browser I am currently unable to mimic the browser behaviour within Python.

Comment: Without detail information for reproducing your problem.
It is hard to answer. My understanding, you looking for `How to get an access token without Browser by Python from Keycloak?` Correct?

Comment: I am looking for `How to access self hosted Gitlab Instance via Python that has a SAML Integration with Keycloak (that has enabled Kerberos) enabled`

Comment: Or formulated differently: `My Gitlab Instance has SAML Login active to authenticate with an Keycloak instance via Kerberos. When I enter the Page via the Browser the user is logged without entering a password. How can I mimic this behaviour with a Python script`

Comment: I don't know SSO SAML login via Kerberos. Generally getting access token by Python with grand_type is password. It can skip login steps. This thread shows how to get it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068333/keycloak-api-identify-users-realm-for-login/73083304#73083304